# concat is not defined error when printing function to console

Tags: javascript, string, random, concatenation

I'm getting an error below when running the below code, the code works until the last function where this error occurs. The code is to pick a random number and random words from the beginning functions and then concatenate them in the final function as one string, the output should be something like: 7 happy cats jumping.

ReferenceError: concat is not defined

```
//function to generate and display to console Word 1 - Random Number.
function Word1(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(1);
    max = Math.floor(9);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
const Random_Number = Word1()
console.log(Random_Number);

//Function to generate and display to console Word 2 - Random Emotion.
function Word2(word)
{
    return word[Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length)];
}

var word = ["Happiness", "Sadness", "Fear", "Disgust", "Anger", "Suprise"];
console.log(Word2(word));


//Function to generate and display to console Word 3 - Random plural noun.
function Word3(noun)
{
    return noun[Math.floor(Math.random() * noun.length)];
}

var noun = ["Noun", "Monday", "Program", "Pizza", "Computer", "Suprise"];
console.log(Word3(noun)+ "s");

//Function to generate and display to console Word 4 - Random verb.
function Word4(verb)
{
    return verb[Math.floor(Math.random() * verb.length)];
}

var verb = ["Accept", "Hope", "Jump", "Lend", "Relax", "Damage"];
console.log(Word4(verb));
 
//Function to create password one-line string.
function password(passWord)
{
    return passWord[concat(Word1 + " " + Word2 + " " + Word3 + " " + Word4)];
}
var passWord = password();
console.log(password);
```

Comment: You haven't defined the `concat` method. That's why it gives the error `ReferenceError: concat is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems you need to fix

**1)** If you are not using `min` and `max` in the function `Word1` then why are you passing the parameter to it.

**2)** You should store the result of `Word2(word)`, `Word3(noun) + "s"` and   `Word4(verb)` in a variable so that you can access it anywhere in the code.

**3)** Since you are concatenating the result of all words then you can use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as

```
`${Random_Number} ${w2} ${w3} ${w4}`
```

```js
//function to generate and display to console Word 1 - Random Number.
function Word1(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(1);
  max = Math.floor(9);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
const Random_Number = Word1();
console.log(Random_Number);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

var word = ["Happiness", "Sadness", "Fear", "Disgust", "Anger", "Suprise"];
//Function to generate and display to console Word 2 - Random Emotion.
function Word2(word) {
  return word[Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length)];
}

const w2 = Word2(word);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

var noun = ["Noun", "Monday", "Program", "Pizza", "Computer", "Suprise"];
//Function to generate and display to console Word 3 - Random plural noun.
function Word3(noun) {
  return noun[Math.floor(Math.random() * noun.length)];
}

const w3 = Word3(noun) + "s";
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

var verb = ["Accept", "Hope", "Jump", "Lend", "Relax", "Damage"];
//Function to generate and display to console Word 4 - Random verb.
function Word4(verb) {
  return verb[Math.floor(Math.random() * verb.length)];
}

const w4 = Word4(verb);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Function to create password one-line string.
function password() {
  return `${Random_Number} ${w2} ${w3} ${w4}`;
}
var generatedPassword = password();
console.log(generatedPassword);
```

I'd like to simplify the program more

```js
const generateRandomNumber = (arr) => Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

const Word1 = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
const Word2 = (word) => word[generateRandomNumber(word)];
const Word3 = (noun) => noun[generateRandomNumber(noun)];
const Word4 = (verb) => verb[generateRandomNumber(verb)];

const Random_Number = Word1(1, 9);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
var word = ["Happiness", "Sadness", "Fear", "Disgust", "Anger", "Suprise"];
const w2 = Word2(word);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

var noun = ["Noun", "Monday", "Program", "Pizza", "Computer", "Suprise"];
const w3 = Word3(noun) + "s";
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

var verb = ["Accept", "Hope", "Jump", "Lend", "Relax", "Damage"];
const w4 = Word4(verb);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Function to create password one-line string.
const password = () => `${Random_Number} ${w2} ${w3} ${w4}`;
var generatedPassword = password();
console.log(generatedPassword);
```

Which you can more simplify

```js
const generateRandomNumber = (len) => Math.floor(Math.random() * len);

const Word1 = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
const getWord = (arr) => arr[generateRandomNumber(arr.length)];

const Random_Number = Word1(1, 9);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
var word = ["Happiness", "Sadness", "Fear", "Disgust", "Anger", "Suprise"];
const w2 = getWord(word);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

var noun = ["Noun", "Monday", "Program", "Pizza", "Computer", "Suprise"];
const w3 = getWord(noun) + "s";
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

var verb = ["Accept", "Hope", "Jump", "Lend", "Relax", "Damage"];
const w4 = getWord(verb);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Function to create password one-line string.
const password = () => `${Random_Number} ${w2} ${w3} ${w4}`;
var generatedPassword = password();
console.log(generatedPassword);
```

This is the cleanest code

```js
const generateRandomNumber = (min, max) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

const getWord = (arr) => arr[generateRandomNumber(0, arr.length)];

const Random_Number = generateRandomNumber(1, 9);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
var word = ["Happiness", "Sadness", "Fear", "Disgust", "Anger", "Suprise"];
const w2 = getWord(word);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

var noun = ["Noun", "Monday", "Program", "Pizza", "Computer", "Suprise"];
const w3 = getWord(noun) + "s";
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

var verb = ["Accept", "Hope", "Jump", "Lend", "Relax", "Damage"];
const w4 = getWord(verb);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Function to create password one-line string.
const password = () => `${Random_Number} ${w2} ${w3} ${w4}`;
var generatedPassword = password();
console.log(generatedPassword);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's fixed the issue. I'm a student just learning JavaScript (and new to stackoverflow) so this info was very handy!

Comment: @MadMike I've added the clean version. Have a look it is clean and easy to understand and easy to debug.

Comment: Just see the step-by-step simplification. It would help you to write clean code

Answer (score 0):

you need to write code like this

```
   function password(passWord)
{
    return passWord[Word1.concat(Word2 + " " + Word3 + " " + Word4)];
}
```

Comment: `Word1` is a function. How can you use `concat` on it?